# How to encrypt a files in Jenkins

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, encryption

I am trying to run Node.js app from jenkins which takes a backup of our API management platform.
When we get a backup on jenkins server, we have below directories -
Backup

```
├── apps
├── secretes
│   ├── abc
│   ├── pqr
│   └── xyz
└─ devs
```

There are directories in secrets like `abc`, `pqr`, `xyz` which store some .txt files in it which has confidential data.

I want to encrypt all files present in the `secretes` directory before creating a zip and placing it in backup storage location. Any encryption method will work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an external tool such as [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to create a strongly encrypted zip file.

Install it by using this command `sudo apt-get install p7zip-full -y`

Encrypt your Jenkins's secretes directory by using the following command;

```
7z a -mhe=on -t7z -mx=9 -pyour_custom_password output_encryped_backup_archive.7z secretes
```

You can read more about the above options at https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z

You can automate this script by using crontab.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1. Jenkins credentials plugin

Store all credentials/secrets in one place.

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

example

```
node {
  ws {
    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'secret', variable: 'FILE')]) {
      sh 'use $FILE'
    }
  }
}
```

Options 2. git-crypt

Just store as is into git with module git-crypt. In Jenkins credentials you have store the key

https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt

to get data just checkout git with additional encryption key

Option 3. Store encrypted archive in acrtifactory/S3 and password in Jenkins credentials

e.g. from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/

```
node {
  withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    sh '''
      set +x
      curl -u "$USERPASS" https://private.server/ > output
    '''
  }
}
```